# Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value, reactjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I am working on a project where the post has many comments, and I am trying to take the amount of the comments and display them in the UI.

but I am getting error

```
Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value
```

and this is the server-side:

```
router.get("/commentsCounter/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const PostId = req.body.PostId;

  const commentsCounter = await Comments.count({
    where:{
      id: PostId,
    }
  });
  res.json({ commentsCounter });
  console.log("commentsCounter", commentsCounter);
});
```

and this is the client-side:

```
     useEffect((PostId) => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3007/comments/commentsCounter/${id}`).then((res) => {
      console.log('setCommentsCounter', res.data.commentsCounter)

      setCommentsCounter(res.data.commentsCounter)
    });
  }, []);
```

any suggestions?
thank you:)

Comment: You are making a `get` request. Try `req.params.id`

Comment: ok I tried but it returned an zero (0)

Comment: {commentsCounter.id} 

this is where I am rendering it to display in the ui

Comment: try console logging you `id` var in frontend, before making a request (i.e. `${id}`).

Comment: ok, this is the result.     CommentsCounter undefined

Comment: Then you are sending wrong id from the front end. What you send from front-end, will same appear in backend

Answer (score 1):

You should get the request `id` from `request.params.id` not from the `request.body`

The `request.body` contain only data sent to the server via `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` and not via `GET` method. you have define the route as `GET` method with that the body of the request will always be **empty**.

As you have define the route of the request handler as `router.get("/commentsCounter/:id", ...)` you can access `id` params like this

```
router.get("/commentsCounter/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const PostId = req.params.id;

    // here the PostId will be equal to the id in the URL
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I tried this as you said, like this but it returned undefined.

router.get("/commentsCounter/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const PostId = req.params.id;

  const commentsCounter = await Comments.count({
    where:{
      id: PostId,
    }
  });
  res.json({ commentsCounter });
  console.log("commentsCounter",  req.params.PostId);
});

Comment: what is the exact URL you are trying to access from the browser

Comment: through localhost

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the id wrong, it should be something like req.params.id or req.query.id depending on the framework you're using.

Comment: Yeah, you are right but when I tried req. params.id it just returned zero